# Is calculating the distance between two floating-point numbers symmetrical?

Tags: java, floating-point, distance

For a Java program, I wrote a method to calculate the distance between two floating-point numbers.
It is very important that this method works symmetrically for the input order.
Currently I'm using the method:

```
double distanceBetween(double a, double b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);  // I assume that a-b = -(b-a)
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is always symmetrical, or if I should change the code to:

```
double distanceBetween(double a, double b) {
    if (a > b) return a - b;
    else return b - a;
}
```

So my question is, is

```
Math.abs(a - b) == Math.abs(b - a)
```

guaranteed to be always true for all values for a and b?
Or is it possible that in some cases (due to the use of floating-point math) the result isn't *exactly* the same?

Comment: side note warning: NaNs are not equal to each other, so if `a` or `b` is NaN - then `Math.abs(a - b) == Math.abs(b - a)` will be false, but probably it is not a big problem here

Comment: Although not a proof one way or the other you could write a program to generate millions of random floating point numbers and check it out in a loop. You could even manipulate the delta between numbers to check possible border cases (where the numbers are very close).

Comment: @IłyaBurso Yes, you're right. But for my application I don't have to deal with NaN.

Comment: @WJS In the past I did some floating-point tests with random numbers to check out what operations works in the same way one would expect from mathematics. But I made some bad experience here, because even thought I tested it with millions of random numbers, some operations always worked fine, but when I input 'normal' values then some operations failed. So I believe that random generated numbers are only a (small) subset of the available numbers.

Comment: Obviously it would be true for `BigDecimal` (*if* they were constructed properly from `String`s)

Comment: Using IEEE math, `abs(x)==abs(-x)` and `(a-b) == -(b-a)` (ignoring `NaN != NaN`). However, I'm not sure if Java is allowed to do some aggressive fast-math optimizations, e.g. `a*b - c*d` --> `fma(a, b, -c*d)`.

Comment: @chtz: Re “Using IEEE math, … `(a-b) == -(b-a)`”: That is not true with asymmetric rounding methods, such as round-toward-infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is calculating the distance between two floating-point numbers symmetrical?

Yes in Java’s native floating-point operations, no in other languages when asymmetric rounding methods are used, and possibly no in Java’s `BigDecimal` when asymmetric rounding methods are used (see end).

IEEE 754-2019 5.1 says:

> … Unless otherwise specified, each of the computational operations specified by this standard that returns a numeric result shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that intermediate result, if necessary, to fit in the destination’s format (see 4 and 7)…

Subtraction and absolute value are operations specified by the standard that return a numeric result, and there is no “otherwise specified” statement for them. IEEE 754 floating-point formats are symmetric with regard to sign; for any representable number *x*, −*x* is also representable. So, with any symmetric rounding method, if *a*−*b* is rounded to some number *x*, then *b*−*a* is rounded to −*x*.

IEEE 754 specifies asymmetric rounding modes, such as round-toward-infinity (round upward). With an asymmetric rounding mode, *a*−*b* will not always be rounded symmetrically to *b*−*a*. For example, with a hypothetical two-digit decimal floating-point, `14 - 1.7` would produce a result of 13 (14 − 1.7 = 12.3, and that is rounded upward to 13), but 1.7 − 14 would produce −12 (1.7 − 14 = −12.3, and that is rounded upward to −12).

However, Java does not use asymmetric rounding modes for its native floating-point operations ([*The Java Virtual Machine Specification*, Java SE 18 Edition, 2022-02-23, section 2.8, page 20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se18/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.8)).

Taking the absolute value never rounds because its mathematical result is always representable, so it is not a factor in the analysis.

Java’s `BigDecimal` has some support for asymmetric rounding methods, but it is not clear to me whether these are built into operations (*i.e.*, will be performed automatically during a subtraction) or must be manually applied. If the former is the cae, then *a*−*b* and *b*−*a* will not always produce symmetric results in `BigDecimal`.

Comment: For convenience, [link to cited section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se18/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.8) of JVM Specification.

Comment: @VGR: You are welcome to edit such links into a post.